# Ktor Framework using content negotiation with framemaker

Tags: kotlin, ktor, content-negotiation

New to Kotlin and Ktor. I generated Ktor app using both Jackson Serialization and Framemaker. I allowed sample code to be included.

Using Chrome browser and accessing the endpoint returning text worked fine. The other endpoint returning html returned json instead???

I noticed that if i remove the install of the Content Negotiation plugin, html is returned correctly.

Am i correct in assuming that i cannot mix the use of the Content Negotiation plugin and endpoints that also return html?